# Should I be worried about these temperatures?

Tags: power-supply, cooling, temperature

I just installed a new [nVidia GeForece GTX 680](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2313386&tab=7&SRCCODE=WEBLET03ORDER&cm_mmc=Email-_-WebletMain-_-WEBLET03ORDER-_-Deals&utm_source=EML&utm_medium=main&utm_campaign=WEBLET03ORDER&cm_lm=dgp1130422@gmail.com) as well as a [TX 750 V2](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=7195038&tab=7&SRCCODE=WEBLET03ORDER&cm_mmc=Email-_-WebletMain-_-WEBLET03ORDER-_-Deals&utm_source=EML&utm_medium=main&utm_campaign=WEBLET03ORDER&cm_lm=dgp1130422@gmail.com) power supply. They seem to run fine, but I installed SpeedFan and HWMonitor to check the temperatures and the values are worrying me. (The programs agree on temp, but I should point out that SpeedFan says I have only one fan running at 30,000+ RPM, while HW is much more reasonable in its estimates.)

```
GPU: 40 - 45 C
Temp1: ~50 C
Temp2: 74 - 77 C
Temp3: ~60 C 
Core: ~55 C
```

(This is at idle on Desktop btw)

I do not know what Temp 1, 2, or 3 are referring to, Google says these values aren't always good, but I'm feeling the components and I'm no so sure those temps are bogus. The GPU is warm, though I'm not sure how hot it should be at the desktop. PSU is borderline warm, but the Motherboard feels pretty hot and it worries me.

I'm just a bit unsure on what's normal or what to do. I've only ever bought pre-built PC's, and I've only upgraded RAM before. Is this something I should be concerned with?

Comment: does your motherboard with any overclocking/monitoring software? if so, you may be able to compare readings to determine what Temp1-3 are. Keep in mind those names are just arbitrary names for unknown sensors. they may or may not be important. on a personal note, I wouldn't be comfortable with those temps at idle, for any component, but you are not maxed out or anything. your vid card looks average, and they usually run a little hot. I take a more serious approach to cooling than the people who hate noise, but I'd shoot to keep everything under 45 when idle, and upper 30's is better.

Answer (score 1):

These temperatures are fine. You should worry when they exceed 80°C or even 90°C for an extended period of time. Such high temperatures have severe effects on your hardware, e.g. an increased electromigration (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration#Thermal_effects).

I'd advise you to run a couple of stress tests like prime95 on your pc to see how the temperatures are under heavy load. This should help you: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/how-to-stress-test-your-new-pc-to-shake-out-any-faults/16438

Comment: I ran Prime95 and Max Payne 3 simultaneously to test (I realize one's doing CPU while the other is really GPU). Once the core gets upwards of 75 C, the fan speeds up and brings all the temperatures to about 65 C before slowing itself down again and repeating the process. The computer is recognizing that it's getting a little hot and speeding up the fan to cool itself down, so I guess it must be ok with the idle temperatures. If it wasn't, it'd run the fan faster right? I guess that means the machine can take the heat, though those numbers still feel a little high to me.